# Are endgame tablebases included with Stockfish?

Tags: stockfish, tablebases, scid

I just downloaded Stockfish as a .exe file for use with SCID vs PC. Are tablebases included with the executable? If not, how can I make Stockfish use them while analysing a game with SCID vs PC?

I understand that 6-7 piece tablebases are very large, but how about 5-piece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turned my comments above into an answer:

Nope, they aren't included by default. You'd have to download the tablebases you want and then get Stockfish to use them. I haven't done this myself, but this seems to be a good guide: https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/7477uh/how_to_freely_install_a_tablebase_for_stockfish/

As for the size of 5-piece tablebases, those shouldn't be a problem for memory. 6-piece is over 100GB though.